# Do the mathematicians/physicists that come up with these useful formulas picture the equations in their head?

Tags: soft-question, education, math-history

For example in this three blue one brown video he shows the visualization of the derivative of x^2 it's relatively easy to see how it works and intuitively I could see how I could come up with this myself. [image]

On the other hand Schrödingers Equation I don't know how I am supposed to picture this or come up with this my self. [image]

So I guess my question is in order to come up with new formulas do I need to be able to visualize everything or just accept the pervious person formula as an absolute truth and just simply play around with adding things onto it to come up with something new and innovative to solve another problem or something similar ?

Comment: Schrödinger effectively guessed at the equation - although that might be a bit too strong. It is remarkable and no one has been able to improve upon it.

Comment: please accept major results as truth  and practice correct manipulation of formulas. In time, you will  learn various aspects of background.

Comment: Another extraordinary example is the set of Maxwell equations...

Comment: so @Moo you saying he just had a general hypothesis and then he just started plugging random stuff in (within reason) until it worked ?

Comment: https://phys.org/news/2013-04-schrodinger-equation.html

Comment: For Schrodinger's equation, there is a more general and simpler version of the equation that basically says time evolution is unitary: $\langle\Psi(t)\vert = \hat{U}\langle\Psi(0)\vert$. Here $\hat{U}$ is a unitary operator, and it is a mathematical theorem that one can write $\hat{U} = e^{i\hat{H}t/\hbar}$ for some operator $\hat{H}$, which is called the Hamiltonian.

The equation you wrote down is a corollary of this equation for a specific choice of $\hat{H} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \hat{V}$.

Comment: A lot of major discoveries occur as a result of methods and discoveries made by others. For example, it is easier for someone to make a discovery in group theory if they have a strong grasp of the subject and previous results. On the other hand, many times people's personal experiences cause them to generate new ideas and analogies.

Comment: so @FabrizzioMuzz what your saying is that it is a combination of being able to picture part of it with your own mathematical intuition and part of it by relying on the discoveries of others

Comment: I can just share my personal experience (that isn't too much). First, there exists an huge backgroud to the mathematics of Schrodinger's equations, as does the Einstein's field equations etc. and the gap betwen what you're capable of understanding now and all this mathematics. Give time to time and take it easy, intuition does not came just from geometrical insights, but is built with practice. A good way to do it is trying to figure out (partially) by yourself, but don't waste a lot of time on it, because, as you said, exists a lot of new problems to solve.

Comment: @Stef Yes. See Paulo Estêvão's comment above.

Comment: I find pictures can be a useful way to build intuition of the formulas but they're not always useful or important. For example if I'm using probabilistic coordinates for a roshambo strategy it can be interpreted as a barycentric coordinates of a triangle. I can then use some geometric notions to try and understand what an optimal counter-strategy is to any other strategy. So despite not being geometric that form can make otherwise formulaic expression easier to understand intuitively.

Comment: Thanks @CyclotomicField for helping me again. Totally makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding visualization: Pictures are often useful to understand a specific concept in a pure form but often different concepts are combined to such an extent that the whole cannot really be imagined as a picture anymore. Just try to imagine the derivative of $5x^5+3x^4+3x^3+2x^2-x+2$ as a picture. Schrödinger's equation tells a whole story. It's hard to summarize the Odyssey in one picture and in the same way, advanced mathematics is hard to grasp in one picture. Pictures may explain part of it or help you understand a certain aspect but you shouldn't expect everything to be explainable by a simple picture.

Visualization isn't the only way to understand things better. As human beings, we are all equipped with a variety of systems to understand the world. Visualization is one of them, but game theory can be another helpful one (if I say this how will someone else disprove me?), not to mention words, the explanation mechanism we are using in this text. If you do mathematics long enough you may develop intuition that cannot even easily be described through pictures, words or games. You may find some mathematical ideas innately beautiful or be able to draw analogies between different fields or disciplines.

Your question is a good one: how to come up with the formulas, instead of just using them? Usually, they arise when you're faced with a problem that you want to solve.

Schrödinger was looking at physics phenomena for a long time before coming up with his formula. He also had already seen many systems of differential equations work out well for other problems. He had a good grasp of which units played a role, which variables and which constants. He understood well how linear operators work and how you can use them. He had a good understanding of differentials, exponentials, complex numbers and a lot of advanced maths. He may or may not have liked cats. He then combined all of these tools into a solution for the problem which he faced. So to come up with the formula, you would need to have all of that background in both maths and physics.

More generally then, how do you come up with a formula? That depends on what you're working on. But in general, here are a few questions you should ask yourself when you're trying to come up with a formula:

- What is the problem you're trying to solve?
- How accurate does the formula need to be?
- What are some example scenarios in which you would want to use the formula? What would you be inputting into the formula and what would the outcome be?
- Which variables and constants are likely to appear in the formula?
- What are the domains of the relevant variables?
- Which mathematical operations are likely needed in the formula? (Does it make sense for there to be an exponential function? Or is it likely that it involves a derivative?)
- How complicated is the formula likely / allowed to be?
- What other formulas already exist and how can they be applied and combined for this specific problem?
- What similar problems exist and what solutions have been proposed for those?

Comment: Wow that was exactly the explanation I needed thank you so much !